# How to cast a void pointer to an int?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a `void* pointer`. I want to cast the value at that pointer to an int and add it the value at another `void* x`. I have already tried:

```
x += (int)(*pointer);
```

But this gives me a `operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required` error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your title asks about casting a `void*` pointer value to `int`, but your question is about retrieving an `int` value from the address to which a `void*` pointer points. They're two very different things.

Comment: "I want to cast the value at that pointer to an int" or do you want to cast that to an `int *`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't dereference a pointer to void. That would return a value of type `void`, which doesn't exist.

You have to cast the pointer to an `int*`, then dereference that.

```
x += *(int*)pointer;
```